# Automatic keyword highlighting in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out, how can I create some DOM elements, for example a `<div>` so I can use it as a special code placeholder. (Not the default `<code>` tag)

For example, I use `<div>`'s (with some class) and any words in that `<div>` that are like, keywords in some programming language, they will change color automatically - depending which sort of keyword they are; `string`, `number`, `function` etc.

[Here's an example](http://craig.is/making/rainbows)

That page has multiple `<div>`'s and all keywords in them are in some special color.

How can I make that?

Comment: If you've tried anything yet, post what you've tried and you're more likely to get folks to help.

Comment: I think that link you posted answers your own question.

Comment: Yeah I kind of answered the question, in the question. Sorry, just got confused a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's fairly straight-forward - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yps3F/).

The variations on the theme are truly infinite.

CSS

```
.bigred {
    font-size: 21px;
    color: red;
}
.littlegreen {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: green;
}
.blueitalic {
    fond-size: 18px;
    color: blue;
    font-style: italic;
}
```